# chrome auto logs into netflix but the password saved is incorrect?

Tags: google-chrome, netflix

How am I able to use netflix when the password saved in chrome is incorrect? This is very strange.

I forgot my password and would like to retrieve it without resetting it.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you would be pretty upset if anyone could just jump on your computer and get your netflix password.

I know in firefox you used to be able to see stored passwords but I am not sure if that is still the case.

Reset it.